# Combining monads in Haskell

Tags: haskell, io, state-monad

I am trying to write a Spider Solitaire player as a Haskell learning exercise.

My `main` function will call a `playGame` function once for each game (using `mapM`), passing in the game number and a random generator (`StdGen`). The `playGame` function should return a `Control.Monad.State` monad and an IO monad that contains a `String` showing the game tableau and a `Bool` indicating if the game was won or lost.

How do I combine the `State` monad with the `IO` monad for the return value? What should the type declaration for `playGame be?

```
playGame :: Int -> StdGen a -> State IO (String, Bool)
```

Is the `State IO (String, Bool)` correct? If not, what should it be?

In `main`, I plan on using

```
do
  -- get the number of games from the command line (already written)
  results <- mapM (\game -> playGame game getStdGen) [1..numberOfGames]
```

Is this the correct way to call `playGame`?

Comment: You might also enjoy `RandT` from the [MonadRandom](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadRandom) package.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What you want is `StateT s IO (String, Bool)`, where `StateT` is provided by both `Control.Monad.State` (from the `mtl` package) and `Control.Monad.Trans.State` (from the `transformers` package).

This general phenomenon is called a monad transformer, and you can read a great introduction to them in [Monad Transformers, Step by Step](https://web.archive.org/web/20201101000000*/https://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/scravy/realworldhaskell/materialien/monad-transformers-step-by-step.pdf).

There are two approaches to defining them.  One of them is found in the `transformers` package which uses the `MonadTrans` class to implement them.  The second approach is found in the `mtl` class and uses a separate type-class for each monad.

The advantage of the `transformers` approach is the use of a single type-class to implement everything (found [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/transformers/0.2.2.0/doc/html/Control-Monad-Trans-Class.html#t:MonadTrans)):

```
class MonadTrans t where
    lift :: Monad m => m a -> t m a
```

`lift` has two nice properties which any instance of `MonadTrans` must satisfy:

```
(lift .) return = return
(lift .) f >=> (lift .) g = (lift .) (f >=> g)
```

These are the functor laws in disguise, where `(lift .) = fmap`, `return = id` and `(>=>) = (.)`.

The `mtl` type-class approach has its benefits, too, and some things can only be cleanly solved using the `mtl` type-classes, however the disadvantage is then that each `mtl` type-class has its own set of laws you have to remember when implement instances for it.  For example, the `MonadError` type-class (found [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mtl/1.1.0.2/doc/html/Control-Monad-Error-Class.html#t:MonadError))is defined as:

```
class Monad m => MonadError e m | m -> e where
    throwError :: e -> m a
    catchError :: m a -> (e -> m a) -> m a
```

This class comes with laws, too:

```
m `catchError` throwError = m
(throwError e) `catchError` f = f e
(m `catchError` f) `catchError` g = m `catchError` (\e -> f e `catchError` g)
```

These are just the monad laws in disguise, where `throwError = return` and `catchError = (>>=)` (and the monad laws are the category laws in disguise, where `return = id` and `(>=>) = (.)`).

For your specific problem, the way you would write your program would be the same:

```
do
  -- get the number of games from the command line (already written)
  results <- mapM (\game -> playGame game getStdGen) [1..numberOfGames]
```

... but when you write your `playGame` function it would look either like:

```
-- transformers approach :: (Num s) => StateT s IO ()
do x <- get
   y <- lift $ someIOAction
   put $ x + y

-- mtl approach :: (Num s, MonadState s m, MonadIO m) => m ()
do x <- get
   y <- liftIO $ someIOAction
   put $ x + y
```

There are more differences between the approaches that become more apparent when you start stacking more than one monad transformer, but I think that's a good start for now.

Comment: Very nice and complete answer. Thanks.

Comment: `StateT IO (String, Bool)` is incorrect – a kind mismatch. It's `StateT s m a` with `s` the state type and `m` a monad, and `a` the result type.

Comment: Also, the `mtl` approach and the `transformers` approach really aren't different ways of doing the same thing – `MonadError` achieves a different goal from `MonadTrans`. And the laws aren't the `Monad` laws in disguise – they're very *similar*, but the types of the things involved, and their meaning, is different. I mean, they're basically a unit law and an associative law, but with respect to entirely different operations.

Comment: @benmachine Thanks, fixed.  Also, the `MonadError` laws are actually just type-restricted versions of the monad laws because the `e` is hidden in the `m` via the functional dependency so you can't access the full power of them, but you can still use those laws to verify that you implement an instance correctly.

Comment: I'm not sure your new type *is* what he wants – what is the `s` for? With regard to the MonadError stuff, I can sort of see what you mean, but I'm not sure the analogy is as fundamental as you put it – I think the fact that the error type is determined by the monad, not the user, is an important difference. And I stand by my comment that the `mtl` and `transformers` approach are very much solving different problems – note that nowadays `mtl` *imports and uses* `transformers` heavily, so it's strange to imply that they are competing.

Comment: For `MonadError`, begin from the specific case of `Either e a`.  Now flip the type arguments to `type EitherR a e = Either e a`.  This forms a "success" monad, where `(>>=) :: EitherR a e1 -> (e1 -> EitherR a e2) -> EitherR a e2`.  Now, type restrict that to: `(>>=) :: EitherR a e -> (e -> EitherR a e) -> EitherR a e`.  Next, go back to `Either`: `(>>=) :: Either e a -> (e -> Either e a) -> Either e a)`.  Finally, replace `Either e` with `m | m -> e`: `(>>=) :: m a -> (e -> m a) -> m a`.  This is what I mean.

Comment: I read the paper you mentioned, "Monad Transformers, Step by Step". Very nice paper.

Comment: Okay, I'll revoke my downvote. I still don't think this is a great answer, but I suppose it's not outright wrong.

Answer (score 8):

`State` is a monad, and `IO` is a monad. What you're trying to write from scratch is called a "monad transformer", and the Haskell standard library already defines what you need.

Have a look at the state monad transformer `StateT`: it has a parameter which is the inner monad you want to wrap into the `State`.

Each monad transformer implements a bunch of typeclasses, such that for each instance, the transformer deals with it every time it can (e.g. the state transformer is only able to directly handle state-related functions), or it propagates the call to the inner monad in such a way that when you can stack all the transformers you want, and have a uniform interface to access to the features of all of them. It's a sort of [chain of responsibility](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternChain.aspx), if you want to look at it this way.

If you look on [hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/transformers/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Lazy.html#g:2), or do a quick search on stack overflow or google you'll find lots of examples of usages of `StateT`.

**edit**: Another interesting reading is [Monad Transformers Explained](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monad_Transformers_Explained).

Comment: I like how one rediscovers the wheel several times learning Haskell... It's actually pretty nice to find a solution to a problem and find out, that it's a general design pattern.

Comment: @FUZxxl: Yes, it is indeed :)

Answer (score 2):

Okay, a few things to clear up here:

- You can't "return a monad". A monad is a kind of *type*, not a kind of value (to be precise, a monad is a *type constructor* that has an instance of the `Monad` class). I know this sounds pedantic, but it might help you sort out the distinction between things and types-of-things in your head, which is important.
- Note that you can't do anything with `State` that is impossible without it, so if you're confused about how to use it, then don't feel you need to! Often, I just write the ordinary function type I want, and then if I notice I have a lot of functions shaped like `Thing -> (Thing, a)` I would go "aha, this looks a bit like `State`, maybe this can be simplified to `State Thing a`". Understanding and working with plain functions is an important first step on the road to using `State` or its friends.
- `IO`, on the other hand, is the only thing that can do its job. But the name `playGame` doesn't immediately spring out at me as the name of something that needs to do I/O. In particular, if you *only* need (pseudo-)random numbers, you can do that without `IO`. As a commenter has pointed out, [MonadRandom](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadRandom) is great for making this simple, but again you can just use pure functions that take and returning a `StdGen` from `System.Random`. You just have to make sure you thread your seed (the `StdGen`) correctly (doing this automatically was basically why `State` was invented; you might find you understand it better after trying to program without it!)
- Finally, you're not quite using `getStdGen` correctly. It's an `IO` action, so you need to bind its result with `<-` in a `do`-block before using it (technically, you don't *need* to, you have lots of options, but that's almost certainly what you want to do). Something like this:

  ```
  do
    seed <- getStdGen
    results <- mapM (\game -> playGame game seed) [1..numberOfGames]
  ```

  Here `playGame :: Integer -> StdGen -> IO (String, Bool)`. Notice, however, that you're passing the *same* random seed to each `playGame`, which may or may not be what you want. If it isn't, well, you could return the seed from each `playGame` when you were done with it, to pass to the next one, or repeatedly get new seeds with `newStdGen` (which you could do from inside `playGame`, if you decide to keep it in `IO`).

Anyway, this hasn't been a very structured answer, for which I apologise, but I hope it gives you something to think about.

Comment: "*A monad is a kind of* type, *not a kind of value.*" Wouldn't it be fair to state that it's actually a type constructor?

Comment: Yes, a monad is a kind of type constructor, but I didn't want to sound too technical – I just wanted to emphasise that "monads belong to the world of types". I'll edit it to be more precise.